# How can I add translate attribute in the below code. I am gonna provide translation in .po file

Tags: html, django, translation

```
<th rowspan="2" class="text-center">a1</th>
<th rowspan="2" class="text-center"> a2</th>
<th rowspan="2" class="text-left">a3</th>
<th rowspan="2" class="text-center">a4</th>
```

How can I add translate attribute in the below code. I am gonna provide translation in .po file.

e.g. `<li><a href="/form"><span>{% translate 'I am fine' %} </span></a></li>`

Comment: Translate which attribute?

Comment: e.g. <li><a href="/form"><span>{% translate 'I am fine' %} </span></a></li>